# Jeep Patriot 2009 Model smoke from under hood when in traffic **PLEASE HELP -ADVICE***

Tags: engine, coolant, jeep, radiator

I brought this jeep form a dealership about 6 months ago. When we got it there was nothing wrong it? Took it in for its first service and they advised everything is fine and replaced a few light bulbs.
After this is when the problem started. The car started smoking from under the hood when heading to work we stopped and let the car rest and took it to the dealership around the corner and the radiator cap blew off (we got it replaced) Then not even a week later the car started smoking on the way to work again causing me to pull off on the side of highway (took it in they replaced the entire radiator). They advised to only put water in the car for the next week and it should be fine. We did that then put coolant in as we thought it would surely cook the engine with just water. On the way to work again it started making a tapping flicking sound then the smoking started (on the side of the highway again). We took it in and they kept it for a week not knowing what was wrong with it gave it back and they drained the coolant and just put water back in which we were annoyed about as we wanted them to test it with coolant to figure out the problem. They said you need to drive it under pressure however with just water in the engine I don’t really want to. I drive it but put it in (N) whenever I come to a holt and it doesn’t smoke however the sound of the car when I just turn it on it weird and I’m not sure

Comment: You should take it somewhere else. I'm not familiar with any reasons of why they would want you to use only water with no coolant. When it smokes did you notice your engine temperature?

Comment: yes I check that and its never overheating its always under half way? lately its been at half way at times never over. I'm going to take it somewhere else and see what they say because I know its not right and they are avoiding the problem

Comment: And they changed the thermostat as well last time sorry forgot that

Comment: By asking you to run with only water, it was to probably save you money instead of wasting coolant while the problem was identified... But it's your money... A short interval with only water will not cause harm...